# getting jdk and intellicode errors in vs code. how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I am a very early beginner to coding. I downloaded VS Code so that I could, you know, have somewhere to code in Java. However, I keep getting these two errors telling me these two extensions that I already have installed on VS Code are not working [here are the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eotJ1.png). I already searched through the odds and ends of StackOverflow and have tried everything, and nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated.

I inputted some code into settings.json under a "java.configuration.runtimes" thing but nothing in it worked. I conformed it to my installation directories and current Java version

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a JDK (Java Development Kit) installed?

If you are on Windows, you can check by clicking on the start button, and search through applications and programs for a Java folder.

If you are on MacOS or Linux, you can open up the terminal/command line and type in "java -version" and if it is properly installed, it will display the version.

If you do not find a JDK installed, install one from https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/downloads/

Comment: I've downloaded the one in the error message and the one on Oracle. Is there anything else I need to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the **Coding Pack for Java**.

[image]

It would be helpful to follow this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) to get started.